# Bootstrap tab validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to implement validations in my form. When the user clicks next button, then if the required field is invalid then an error should appear, otherwise the next form should appear.

In the next form, if all required fields are valid then the program should submit ajax; otherwise, it should show an error message.

I have created a jsfiddle at jsfiddle.net/amarkotha366/00zmmz9f/2

Please help, as my code is not working properly.

Comment: what is the problem? what is/are not working in your example?

Comment: email and password field not validated with select @zeropoint

Comment: Did you check out my answer? If it answers your question, accept it and upvote please.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with validating email, you just need to change the `type` attribute on your first `input` tag to `email` instead of `text`.

For validating password, there are lots of plugins. But in a simple fast way, you can do something like this on your `next` button `click` action:

```
// validating password
if ($("#password").val() != $("#confirm_password").val()) {
    // do whatever your want here
    return;
}
```

Check out a working example of your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/00zmmz9f/8/)